# Intercommunication between asp.net core web Api using RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, microservices, asp.net-core-webapi

I have two web api.

One publish a message when specific controller be call (work)

One subscribe to receive message. (not work)

[image: Solution folder]

Here is config for both web api :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddRawRabbit();

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterRawRabbit("guest:guest@localhost:15672/");
        var container = builder.Build();
    }
```

In web api 1, here is action that publish a message  :

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        EventMessage message = new EventMessage() ;
        var client = BusClientFactory.CreateDefault();

        message = new EventMessage() { id = new Guid(), createDate = DateTime.Now };
            client.PublishAsync<EventMessage>(message);

        Console.WriteLine($"message create {message.ToString()}");
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2",};
    }
}
```

And in web api 2, I dont know how to receive that message,
here is the way that i try but it not work

```
public class Listener
{
    public static void Start()
    {
            var client = BusClientFactory.CreateDefault());

            client.SubscribeAsync<EventMessage>(async (msg, context) => Console.WriteLine($"Recieved:{msg.createDate.ToString()}.");


    }
}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //not working
        Listener.Start();


        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

In this project, im using Rawrabbit, any library with the same scenario will be ok. Thanks

Update: i fix this code, it work

Comment: Did you look at using NServiceBus? https://docs.particular.net/samples/web/

Comment: If you fixed the issue, I recommend the question be deleted. The question is in a format that can't really be easily corrected to make it a good candidate for future readers.

Comment: No, im using RawRabbit that i mentioned in the question. 
I update the correct code in the question, so i think it would be helpful for the others when they meet the same problems.
Btw, thank your recommendations, ill try with it